# Re-numbering an Identity Column

Tags: c#, sql, database, identity

I have a table where i set one column (N) as the "is identity" so it can increment by 1 everytime i added somthing to the table.  How do i re-order N when i delete a row?

For example if i added 5 things to the table, N would go 1,2,3,4,5. But if i delete row 3, N will be 1,2,4,5.  I want it to automatically change the values so it N goes 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Why would you ever want to renumber identifiers? If you must reuse identified then create the identifier as a clustered index.

Answer (score 9):

The "identity" value is not meant to be a "counter" in the sense of your question.  The identity value makes every row unique and is not intended to be modified although it can be changed.  If you need a row counter make it a simple int or bigint, then use a table trigger to update the value on insert and delete.

Comment: I usually dislike answers that say 'you're doing it wrong'. I always assume the OP has their reasons and they should have a direct answer to a direct question. I think this might be the exception.

Comment: @IainMH, often "you are doing it wrong" is the best answer.   It would be unprofessional not to point it out when it is truly a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it, but it would be a *terrible* idea.

Instead it is better not to store this number in the database at all since the number is not associated to the *data* in the rows but to the *order* in which you want them to be retrieved. A better solution is to use a sort order column (which is allowed to include gaps), and use ROW_NUMBER when you select the data to generate the row numbers dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a posh way to do this, but you could select into a tmp table, truncate the original table and re-insert. Be sure to wrap it up in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will impact on the performance of the application. If you need to re-order every IDs, then it should be done at the 
1) Code side (Re-order in the datatable and submit the changes) OR
2) SQL side (via triggers/stored procedures/temporary tables)

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot of work to do what you want and then if you get it wrong you will have race conditions and that will end up creating an issue with data integrity. This is a **very** poor idea.

Now occasionally the client asks for this and the proper action is to say, "No, that is a bad idea. It will cost you significantly more in development and maintenance costs, it will substantially increase your risk of having data mismatched to the wrong record and it will substantially increase your risk of looking up a new record unrelated to the problem when researching something from the past that used the number before." (think about reusing order numbers for instance, the old persson has been provided this order number and  and calls to ask about it but you deleted it and someone else's order is in it's place.) And for all that extra cost and risk, you gain exactly nothing. There are virtually no circumstances where you truly can't skip records except a few obsessive-compulsive managers who don't want to see gaps. Even they usually give in once you explain to them that the process is more likely to cause errors and will cost substantially more. Most of the time this is a self imposed requirement by the dev and there is no excuse at all to ever do this unless you have a client who cannot be persuaded otherwise.